# Iris dataset mean() by species

Tags: r, r-mosaic

I want to create some mean of sepal.length, but divided by species. `Using mosaic` package

```
mean(Sepal.Length~Species)
```

It didn't work

Comment: Unless `Sepal.Length` and `Species` are objects saved in your environment, you haven't done anything to tell `mean` where that data should be coming from. This is basically a typo

Comment: mosaic:::mean(Sepal.Length ~ Species,data=iris), you still need to provide a dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A base R solution

```
aggregate(Sepal.Length ~ Species, data=iris, mean)
     Species Sepal.Length
1     setosa        5.006
2 versicolor        5.936
3  virginica        6.588
```

Answer (score 2):

We need to specify the data

```
mosaic::mean(Sepal.Length ~ Species, data = iris)
#    setosa versicolor  virginica 
#     5.006      5.936      6.588
```

Comment: I think this answer should move to [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562656) post.

Comment: @zx8754  I think the question is specifically about `mosaic::mean`

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`, you can do:

```r
library(dplyr)
iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarise(Mean = mean(Sepal.Length))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  Species     Mean
  <fct>      <dbl>
1 setosa      5.01
2 versicolor  5.94
3 virginica   6.59
```